# My Paint Leaks Memory?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I found this [paint app](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024) and used the Profile/Zombie instrument on it. Apparently the memory keeps on rising when you draw.

I think I found where it's leaking but I can't figure out what's really wrong with it.

Anybody an idea? Here is the problem code:

```
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -= 0;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use Profile - Leaks instrument for detecting leaks. Zombies instrument works by placing NSZombie objects for any deallocated objects, and that is the reason why you see a continuous rise in the number of allocated objects.

Comment: In other words: never enable NSZombies when performing memory profiling, because objects never get deallocated then.